# BroadcastReceiver or Service for long background ops?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm developing an app that periodically fetches data from server. Now I'm using a ScheduledThreadPoolExector, but I think is not clean enough, so I decided to use AlarmManager to create periodic tasks.

Which is better for this tasks: BroadcastReceiver or Service? I've read that one of these have the 10 sec limitations, or do both have this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed a BroadcastReceiver can only live for 10seconds. A service can live longer (depending if Android OS needs resources, it can kill your app).

Your Service can be a 'normal' service or an IntentService (which gets killed automatically after no more Intents are available to process).
I would recommend a IntentService.

You can create an Intent which will be received by the IntentService, and add this Intent to the AlarmManager.

Comment: as @PoweRoy mentioned, just use the `BroadcastReceiver `to get notified from your `AlarmManager` and let a `Service` do the long term work you...